# Find the nearest biquadratic number

Tags: code-golf, sequence, number-theory, integer

A biquadratic number is a number that is the fourth power of another integer, for example: `3^4 = 3*3*3*3 = 81`

Given an integer as input, output the closest biquadratic number.

Here are the first 15 double-squares:

```
1, 16, 81, 256, 625, 1296, 2401, 4096, 6561, 10000, 14641, 20736, 28561, 38416, 50625
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so fewest bytes **in each language** wins

This is OEIS [A000583](https://oeis.org/A000583)

Comment: Interesting to note that this will never tie, as the sequence alternates odd and even numbers.

Comment: you could change the name to "Find the nearest zenzizenzic". https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zenzizenzic

Comment: @Okx oh good point, I didn't even think about ties, but you're right, it does seem to alternate parity

Comment: @Mayube It necessarily does, because the sequence is just `n^4` and `n` alternates in sign.

Comment: That nomenclature of biquadratic is confusing: before seeing the question contents, I thought it were the `2 x n²` numbers: 2, 8, 18, 32, 50, 72, 98, ...

Comment: Isn't that called "quartic"? ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quartic), [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quartic))

Comment: I think it would be beneficial to include some test cases.

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 35 bytes

```python
lambda n:int((n**.5-.75)**.5+.5)**4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU1BDsIwDLvzCh@TtesoMCFN2ksGhyIoTIVsqnbh9YUwfLET2/L8Xh6T7EvsT@UZXpdrgHSjLERSVa6t3bFlFcYpH0qcMhJGQQ5yv5G38FvuNvhCLVFrIEq11zgM0kqem2ZnQf@TkvkF9Hte64o567RYRBLm8gE)

#### How it works

The value *n* at which the output switches from (*k* − 1)<sup>4</sup> to *k*<sup>4</sup> satisfies √(√n − 3/4) + 1/2 = *k*, or *n* = ((k − 1/2)<sup>2</sup> + 3/4)<sup>2</sup> = (*k*<sup>2</sup> − *k* + 1)<sup>2</sup> = ((*k* − 1)<sup>4</sup> + *k*<sup>4</sup> + 1)/2, which is exactly the first integer that’s closer to *k*<sup>4</sup>.

(Works for all *n* ≤ 4504699340341245 = (8192<sup>4</sup> + 8193<sup>4</sup> − 7)/2 > 2<sup>52</sup>, after which floating-point roundoff starts to break it, even though it works mathematically for all *n*.)

Comment: You can save a byte with `round` if you switch to Python 2 which rounds all .5's up.

Answer (score 8):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 35 bytes

This challenge [needed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/131691/find-the-nearest-biquadratic-number/131708#comment323100_131704) a convolution-based approach.

```matlab
@(n)sum(n>conv((1:n).^4,[1 1]/2))^4
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKugp6f330EjT7O4NFcjzy45P69MQ8PQKk9TL85EJ9pQwTBW30hTM87kf5qGhSZXmoYliDABM00sNf8DAA)

#### Explanation

The expression `(1:n).^4` produces the row vector `[1 16 81 256 ... n^4]`.

This vector is then convolved with `[1 1]/2`, which is equivalent to computing the sliding average of blocks of size `2`. This implicitly assumes that the vector is left- and right-padded with `0`. So the first value in the result is `0.5` (average of an implicit `0` and `1`), the second is `8.5` (average of `1` and `16`), etc.

As an example, for `n = 9` the result of `conv((1:n).^4,[1 1]/2)` is

```matlab
0.5 8.5 48.5 168.5 440.5 960.5 1848.5 3248.5 5328.5 3280.5
```

The comparison `n>...` then yields

```matlab
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

and applying `sum(...)` gives `2`. This means that `n` exceeds exactly `2` of the mid-points betwen biquadratic numbers (including the additional mid-point `0.5`). Finally, `^4` raises this to `4` to yield the result, `16`.

Comment: It is even golfier!

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>51</s> 49 bytes

Function monad ftw!

```hs
f n=snd.minimum$(abs.(n-)<$>)>>=zip$(^4)<$>[1..n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hz7Y4L0UvNzMvM7c0V0UjMalYTyNPV9NGxU7Tzs62KrNARSPOBMSNNtTTy4v9n5uYmadgq1BQWhJcUuSTp6CiUJyRXw6k0hQMjUz/AwA)

Explanation:

```hs
                                (^4)<$>[1..n] -- creates a list of fourth powers
            (abs.(n-)<$>)>>=zip               -- creates a list of |n-(4th powers)| and
                                              -- zips it with the 4th powers list
    minimum                                   -- finds the minimum
                                              -- (only first tuple entry matters)
snd                                           -- exctracts the second entry (the 4th power)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
t:4^Yk
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v8TKJC4y@/9/I2MA)

#### Explanation

Consider input `9` as an example.

```
t    % Implicitly input n. Duplicate         
     % STACK: 9, 9
:    % Range [1 2 ... n]
     % STACK: 9, [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
4^   % Raise to 4, element-wise
     % STACK: 9, [1 16 81 256 625 1296 2401 4096 6561]
Yk   % Closest element. Implicitly display
     % STACK: 16
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 5 bytes

```
4S
```

Explanation:

```
       Inclusive range [1 .. input]
      Raise to the  v  power
 4                   4th
       Select the value closest to
    S   the input
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//8PcCR0mH@ZO7QsGElP@/zc0AAA)

Comment: This programming language seems to use Unicode characters ("" and ""). Such characters typically require more than one byte. Are you sure the 5 characters can be stored using only 5 bytes?

Comment: @MartinRosenau [Neim uses a custom codepage](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim/wiki/Code-Page)

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
;I≜+.~^₄∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/39rzUeccbb26uEdNLY86lv//b2T8PwoA)

#### Explanation

```
;I≜          I = 0 / I = 1 / I = -1 / I = 2 / etc. on backtracking
   +.        Output = Input + I
    .~^₄     Output = Something to the power 4
        ∧
```

Answer (score 5):

### Excel, 25 bytes

```
=INT((A1^.5-3/4)^.5+.5)^4
```

Excel updates this to `=INT((A1^0.5-3/4)^0.5+0.5)^4`

Comment: Just a note on convention for excel: it is the de facto standard that Excel and Excel VBA function that take input from the `Excel.ActiveSheet` object take them from cell `A1`

Comment: @TaylorScott, thanks for pointing that out.  Have updated.

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, 21 bytes

```
Nearest[Range@#^4,#]&
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
LnnI.x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fJy/PU6/i/39DUwA)

#### Explanation

```
LnnI.x
L      # Push [1 .. input]
 nn    # Raise every element to the 4th power
   I   # Push input
    .x # Closest element in the array to input
```

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES7), 42 bytes

```js
x=>(n=x**.25|0,x-(k=n**4)<++n**4-x?k:n**4)
```

#### Recursive version, 44 bytes

```js
f=(x,k,b)=>(a=k**4)>x?a-x>x-b?b:a:f(x,-~k,a)
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

x=>(n=x**.25|0,x-(k=n**4)<++n**4-x?k:n**4)

console.log(f(16))
console.log(f(48))
console.log(f(49))
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 37 bytes

```matlab
@(n)interp1(t=(1:n).^4,t,n,'nearest')
```

Anonymous function that uses nearest-neighbour interpolation.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKugp6f330EjTzMzryS1qMBQo8RWw9AqT1MvzkSnRCdPRz0vNbEotbhEXfN/moaFJleahqXmfwA)

Comment: @flawr Does [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/131708/36398) make you feel better?

Comment: It does very much so!

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
R*4ạÐṂ
```

A monadic link returning a list of one item, or a full program that prints the result (using an inefficient method).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9Iy@ThroWHJzzc2fT//39DM0sA)**

#### How?

```
R*4ạÐṂ - Link: number, n
R      - range(n) -> [1,2,3,...,n]
 *4    - raise to the fourth power -> [1,16,81,...,n**4]
    ÐṂ - filter keep those (only ever one) minimal:
   ạ   -   absolute difference (with n)
       - if a full program: implicit print (one item lists print their content).
```

Answer (score 2):

## APL, 22 bytes

```
{o/⍨p=⌊/p←|⍵-⍨o←4*⍨⍳⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhOp8/Ue9KwpsH/V06RcA@TWPerfqAkXygWwTLSDjUe9moFAtULXCIRDH0MAAAA)

**How?**

`o←4*⍨⍳⍵` - `o` = range(`⍵`)<sup>4</sup>  <sub>[vectorize]</sub>

`p←|⍵-⍨o` - `p` = abs(`o` - `⍵`)  <sub>[vectorize]</sub>

`o/⍨` - take the `o` element at the index where ...

`p=⌊/p` - the `p` minimum element is

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>10</s> 7 bytes

*Edit: -3 bytes thanks to Razetime*

```
◄≠¹m^4ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8eGOxYYGBv8fTW951Lng0M7cOBOgyP//AA)

```
◄≠¹m^4ḣ
◄               # minimum element based on
 ≠¹             # difference to input,
      ḣ         # of series from 1 up to input
   m^4          # to the power of 4
```

Comment: [min by](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8eGOxYYGBv8fTW951Lng0M7cOBOgyP//AA "Husk – Try It Online")

Comment: @Razetime Will you post that separately, or should I update my (now significantly outgolfed) answer?

Comment: By the way: thanks!  That's the second time you've improved on my answer using minby/maxby... so I guess I should remember them soon...

Comment: go ahead, edit it in

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 9 bytes

```
.maQb^R4S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy83MTApLsgk@P9/UzMA)

---

#### [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 17 bytes

A full program that uses the same arithemtic approach as in [@AndersKaseorg's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/131691/find-the-nearest-biquadratic-number/131700#131700):

```
K.5^s+^-^QK.75KK4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/31vPNK5YO043LtBbz9zU29vk/39TMwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 33 bytes

```php
<?=(($argn**.5-.75)**.5+.5^0)**4;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkqWTNZW8HFLPV0AALaWnpmerqmZtqghjaeqZxBkCWifX//wA)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 56 bytes

```php
<?=2*$argn-($x=($f=$argn**.25^0)**4)>($y=++$f**4)?$y:$x;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkbGysZM1lbwcUtTXSAgvqaqhU2GqopNmCeVpaekamcQaaWlommnYaKpW22toqaSCOvUqllUqF9f//AA)

Answer (score 1):

**C++, 96 bytes**

```
int Q(int N){int i=1;while (pow(i,4)<N){i++;}if (pow(i,4)-N>N-pow(i-1,4)){i--;}return pow(i,4);}
```

Full version:

```
int Q(int N)
{
    int i = 1;

    while (pow(i, 4) < N)
    {
        i++;
    }

    if (pow(i, 4)-N > N-pow(i - 1, 4))
        i--;

    return pow(i,4);
}
```

[LINK to try](https://tio.run/##RY5BCoMwEEXX5hTBbiI2RaG72BwhtEcIMdUBE8UkSJGc3UZLcTMz/82H/9U00U6p7QJWDaHVuIHR@VlLw9HJjPT9recoOLAdttJoN0mlsfMt28B6/CL7FMW6L3jUbOlh0JhM40Lgei@a/VWWLML7hFRwQQ9B6ySTg1IWZ@3DbPHfxOIRYCRYUqAVZUcQQ5kCizn/nWPwuGlSC1Ek6T7Oa0PypwxO54mguNVVhb4)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 35 bytes

```
f n=(floor$(n**0.5-3/4)**0.5+0.5)^4
```

Port of [Anders' Python3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/131700/3913).

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>47</s> <s>44</s> <s>37</s> 35 bytes

```r
n=scan();which.min(((1:n)^4-n)^2)^4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8@2ODkxT0PTujwjMzlDLzczT0NDw9AqTzPORBdIGAHp/yYmhv8B)

Comment: you can return an anonymous function (removing `f=`) and instead of `x[which.min((x-n)^2)]` use `which.min((x-n)^2)^4`, and then put `f=` into the header of the TIO link for testing [like here :)](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jT6fCVsPQKk8zzkSzPCMzOUMvNzNPQ6NCFyhiBBT8n6ZhqcmVpmFhCCJNTAwglKHmfwA)

Comment: @Giuseppe Oh, there is no need to define `x` at all. Thank you!

Comment: ah, then the only other improvement is taking the input from stdin, `n=scan();which.min(((1:n)^4-n)^2)^4` and the input goes into the footer section on TIO.

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks again! Useful to know for future answers in R.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Ç∞§δo╧╖s►M
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=80ec15eb6fcfb773104d&i=200)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/) [`-g`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>20</s> <s>8</s> 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

<s>This feels far too long!</s> I was right!

```
Ç²²ÃñaU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWc&code=x7Kyw/FhVQ&input=ODg4)

```
Ç²²ÃñaU     :Implicit input of integer U
Ç           :Map the range [0,U)
 ²²         :  Square twice
   Ã        :End map
    ñ       :Sort by
     aU     :  Absolute difference with U
            :Implicit output of first element
```

### Without flag, 8 bytes

```
È¬¬v1}cU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=yKysdjF9Y1U&input=ODg4)

```
È¬¬v1}cU     :Implicit input of integer U
È            :Function taking an integer X as argument
 ¬           :  Square root
  ¬          :  Square root
   v1        :  Divisible by 1?
     }       :End function
      cU     :Return the first X in the sequence [U,U-1,U+1,U-2,U+2,U-3,...] that returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 38 bytes

```
{p=q^4~p>:|~p-a>a-o|_Xo\_Xp]\o=p┘q=q+1
```

### Explanation

```
{           DO infinitely
p=q^4       Set p to q quad (q starts out as 1)
~p>:|       IF p exceeds the input THEN
~p-a>a-o    check the distance to p and to o (the last quad) and
|_Xo        PRINT o, or
\_Xp        PRINT p accordingly
]           END IF
\o=p        ELSE  ( p <= input) store p in o to keep track of this quad
┘q=q+1      and raise q for the next iteration
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 64 bytes

```java
n->{int i=0,q,Q=0;while((q=i*i*i*i++)<n)Q=q;return q-n<n-Q?q:Q;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVFdb4IwFH33V9yQmMAEgsYZBjKzx8VshLg9GR46KK4OC7RFZwy/ndWKTm2T3px7z/04t2u0RVZRYrpOf9qy/spJAkmOOIc3RCgcegCdlwskpNkWJIWNjOkLwQhdLWNAbMUNRQVYy3p2LUhuZzVNBCmo/UrFJ0VsH5aYIVEwyCBoqfV8IFQACRyzMqPA8XffJMe6XgXkQd3BwJhSIwoqn2FRMwqVRafUimaVF/lNC@r4qqkstIzlIAJzwSEAincX32ksgINjgtOYZzQ0YfiPRjfIvUFPEk2uEie3eOzeYcl3h9d8994hGaPHSaMcjd9TNpN70dXMSoV30mJcxj/uimFe50Lqy2xUlvn@hcvV6kfi0okNv2Mu9lzgjV3Uwi7lB4lM1/rj1AP5gN7nRp9qJnRJZlfzbINABYbxTAvnmqe9hx8Qzk3AvyVOBE5BgwF0lK7hUUbTa9o/)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>23</s> 34 bytes

I have no idea why `0.75` is such an important number for this, but hey, whatever works.

```ruby
->n{((n**0.5-0.75)**0.5).round**4}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9cur1pDI09Ly0DPVNdAz9xUE8zU1CvKL81L0dIyqf1foJAWnZ5aUqxXkh@fGfvf0NQQAA)

Comment: This will not give the closest biquadratic. E.g. it will return 256 for 151.

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 50 bytes

```
(lambda(x)(expt(floor(+(sqrt(-(sqrt x).75)).5))4))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcVBCoAgEEbhq7j8h8iVUdcxSxAmNTWY25u4eN9zHGruyCXEpuC/6Cyz6mD7nJeFEG7JDZ5TKlhQ39KwzikhvW9EemSIujkGPw)

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 95 bytes

```c#
namespace System.Linq{n=>new int[940].Select((_,i)=>i*i*i*i).OrderBy(i=>Math.Abs(i-n)).First()}
```

We use 940 as a set value as any larger value will overflow the int.

Full/Formatted Version:

```c#
namespace System.Linq
{
    class P
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Func<int, int> f = n => new int[940].Select((_, i) => i * i * i * i).OrderBy(i => Math.Abs(i - n)).First();

            for (int i = 1; i <= Int32.MaxValue; ++i)
                Console.WriteLine($"{i} = {f(i)}");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```