# Subtract my odds from my evens

Tags: code-golf, number, number-theory

Given a non-negative integer, return the absolute difference between the sum of its even digits and the sum of its odd digits.

### Default Rules

- Standard Loopholes apply.
- You can take input and provide output by any standard Input / Output method.
- You may take input as a String, as an Integer or as a list of digits.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes **in every language** wins!

### Test Cases

```
Input ~> Output

0 ~> 0 (|0-0| = 0)
1 ~> 1 (|1-0| = 1)
12 ~> 1 (|2-1| = 1)
333 ~> 9 (|0-(3+3+3)| = 9)
459 ~> 10 (|4-(5+9)| = 10)
2469 ~> 3 (|(2+4+6)-9| = 3)
1234 ~> 2 (|(2+4)-(1+3)| = 2)
```

Comment: May we take input as list of ints?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder That wouldn't be too trivial. It makes the challenge unnecessarily complicated and is an arbitrary requirement that adds bytes.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder [Don't make chameleon challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9384/26600). The most important sentence you might want to look at here is *Combining two or more unrelated core challenges into one — consider splitting the challenge up into separate challenges or dropping unnecessary parts*

Comment: I have changed the rules @Okx. Taking **as a list of digits is now allowed**. I still don't think it would make it to fluffy though.

Comment: `333 ~> 9 (|(3+3+3)-0| = 9)` should be `0-(3+3+3)`, though the outcome is the same.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Ok, fixed

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
-*æ.¹A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/19X6/AyvUM7Hf8f3eNyuF3lUdMa9///DXUUDHQUDI10FIyNjXUUTEwtdRSMTMwsQWLGJgA)

#### How it works

```
-*æ.¹A  Main link. Argument: A (digit array)

-*      Raise -1 to A's digits, yielding 1 for even digits and -1 for odd ones.
    ¹   Identity; yield A.
  æ.    Take the dot product of the units and the digits.
     A  Apply absolute value.
```

Comment: You can save 1 byte by taking input as a list.

Comment: I *am* taking input as a list.

Comment: I'm talking about revision 2.

Comment: `Raise -1 to A's digits, yielding 1 for even digits and 0 for odd ones.` umm, I think you messed something a little bit or something...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Darn off-by-one errors.

Comment: you're probably thinking too binary...at least it was only off by a bit...or two, maybe :)

Answer (score 8):

## SHENZHEN I/O MCxxxx scripts, 197 (126+71) bytes

Chip 1 (MC6000):

- x0: Input as list
- x2: Chip 2 x1
- x3: MC4010

```
mov 0 dat
j:
mov x0 acc
mov 70 x3
mov -1 x3
mov acc x3
mul x3
mov acc x2
mov dat acc
add 1
tlt acc 3
mov acc dat
+jmp j
slx x0
```

Chip 2 (MC4000):

- p0: Output
- x0: MC4010
- x1: Chip 1 x2

```
mov x1 acc
add x1
add x1
mov 30 x0
mov 0 x0
mov acc x0
mov x0 p0
slx x1
```

Comment: (You can us a `<!-- -->` comment to get code right after a list, instead of filler text. Or indent the code with 4 more spaces.)

Answer (score 6):

### Python 2, 39 bytes

Takes integer as list. [Try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/rvYxvzPycxNyklUcHRKjGpWKO4NFdDQ9dQU0srUytTIS2/SCFTITNPwVFT8z@cE22gY6hjpGNopGNsbKxjYmqpY2RiZgnkG5vEWnEpAEFBUWZeiYKPRm5igQaQpZOQmQA0AAA)

```
lambda A:abs(sum((-1)**i*i for i in A))
```

-3 bytes thanks to @Mr.Xcoder
-1 byte thanks to @ovs

Comment: Use `[i,-i][i%2]` instead of `i%2and i or -i` for [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/rvYxvzPycxNyklUcHRKjGpWKO4NFcjOlNHNzM2OlPVKDYtv0ghUyEzT8FRU/N/QVFmXomCj0a0oY6RjrGOSazmfwA).

Comment: `(-1)**i*i` for 39 bytes

Answer (score 5):

## TI-Basic, <s>18</s> 9 bytes

```
abs(sum((-1)^AnsAns
```

**Explanation**

Multiplies each digit in the list by -1 to its power, negating each odd digit, before summing them.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 20 bytes

```
Abs@Tr[(-1)^(g=#)g]&
```

takes as input a list of digits

special thanx to @LLlAMnYP for letting me know about the "new rules"

Comment: beat me to it! :) You probably don't need the `*`.

Comment: now that OP has relaxed the requirements your code can be trivially much shorter. +1

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>59</s> <s>58</s> 57 bytes

```c
i;f(char*v){for(i=0;*v;v++)i+=*v%2?*v-48:48-*v;v=abs(i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dctBC8IgGMbx@z7FEAa@OmGpxUqkL9LFDOs9zMLCy9hnt1XXvD38fzxeXL0vBU2g/uYSyzCHe6JoB8OyyZwDcstyJ48sCz0e9Cg@3brzkyKYpUwOI/V9hu99tblp20fC@AqUdJdTJP06BgJg/sGmCrImSqka6e2@RlLvftYs5Q0)

Comment: If it helps, I have changed the rules and you are now able to take input as a list. Hopefully that would save bytes. I don't know C, so it's just a suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

### R, <strike>30</strike> 29 bytes

```
abs(sum((d=scan())-2*d*d%%2))
```

`d = scan()` takes the input number by one digit after the other.

-1 byte thanks to @Giuseppe!

Comment: This is quite excellent! There's a 1 byte saving to be made, though: `abs(sum((d=scan())-2*d*d%%2))`

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks, good tip, edited!

Answer (score 4):

## C#, 57 bytes

```
namespace System.Linq{i=>Math.Abs(i.Sum(n=>n%2<1?n:-n))}
```

Takes input as `i` and sums the integers by turning the odds to negative.

Comment: First answer here. No clue if I need to wrap this whole thing into a actual C# program and count those bytes too.

Comment: You have to include the boilerplate `namespace System.Linq{` and make an actual function. See the other C# answer for reference

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks for the info. Think I got. Almost doubled my byte count  =(  lol

Comment: Yeah, C# is not really the best golfing language

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Nope, but I thought the rules got relaxed because I saw a slim version on the first page without the namespace stuff and didn't see a `Main`. Only reason I thought I'd answer with it. Oh wells.

Comment: And by the way, **Welcome to PPCG!**

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>43</s> 38 bytes

Takes input as <s>a string</s> an array of digits.

```js
a=>a.map(d=>s+=d&1?d:-d,s=0)&&s>0?s:-s
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

a=>a.map(d=>s+=d&1?d:-d,s=0)&&s>0?s:-s

console.log(f([1]))     // ~> 1 ( |1-0| = 1)
console.log(f([0]))     // ~> 0 ( |0-0| = 0)
console.log(f([1,2]))    // ~> 1 ( |1-2| = 1)
console.log(f([4,5,9]))   // ~> 10 ( |4-(5+9)| = 10)
console.log(f([2,4,6,9]))  // ~> 3 ( |(2+4+6)-9| = 3)
console.log(f([3,3,3]))   // ~> 9 ( |(3+3+3)-0| = 9)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 bytes

```
x_*JpZÃa
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=eF8qSnBaw2E=&input=WzEsMiwzLDRd)

#### Explanation

```
 x_  *JpZÃ a
UxZ{Z*JpZ} a
                Implicit: U = list of digits
UxZ{     }      Take the sum of each item Z in U mapped through the following function:
      JpZ         Return (-1) ** Z
    Z*            times Z. This gives Z if even, -Z if odd.
           a    Take the absolute value of the result.
                Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Answer (score 3):

## APL, 8 bytes

```
|⊢+.×¯1*⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhJpHXYu09Q5PP7TeUAvIBAoqGHClKRiCsIIRkDQGQSBtomCqYAmkjYAsMwVLAA)

**How?**

`¯1*⊢` - -1<sup>n</sup> for `n` in `⍵`

<sub>[`4 5 9` → `1 ¯1 ¯1`]</sub>

`⊢+.×` - verctorized multiplication with `o`, then sum

<sub>[`+/ 4 5 9 × 1 ¯1 ¯1` → `+/ 4 ¯5 ¯9` → `¯10`]</sub>

`|` - absolute value

Comment: Can you please provide a testing environment?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder added

Comment: `|⊢+.×¯1*⊢` with the new input spec.

Comment: @Adám thanks. can't believe I missed product.

Comment: can you provide more detail in the explanation?  can this method be ported to J?  i'm currently using key (see my answer) but this method might shave off a few bytes...

Comment: @Jonah does this edit makes it any clearer?

Comment: @Jonah `[:|]+/ .*_1^]` or `[:|[:+/]*_1^]`

Comment: ty @Adám and Uriel

Comment: You mean to say that APL doesn't have an operator to do this?  I'm *extremely* disappointed...

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
≠0ṁṠ!¡_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HnAoOHOxsf7lygeGhh/P///6MNdYx0jHVMYgE)

Takes a list of digits as input.

Still missing an "abs" builtin, but a good result all the same :)

#### Explanation

`Ṡ!¡_` is a function that takes a number `n` and then applies `n-1` times the function `_` (negation) to `n`. This results in `n` for odd `n` or `-n` for even `n`.

`ṁ` applies a function to each element of a list and sums the results.

`≠0` returns the absolute difference between a number and 0.

Answer (score 3):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 7 bytes

```
ΓDᛃΞ}
```

Explanation:

```
Γ        Apply the following to each element in the input array
 D         Duplicate
  ᛃ        Modulo 2, then perform logical NOT
   Ξ       If truthy, then:
            Multiply by -1
      }  Close all currently running loops/conditionals etc
        Sum the resulting array
```

Comment: Who doesn't have a builtin that mods by 2 then logically NOTs the result?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing It's basically 'check if even'

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 67 bytes

```
(s=#;Abs[Subtract@@(Tr@Select[IntegerDigits@s,#]&/@{EvenQ,OddQ})])&
```

Answer (score 3):

***EDIT: A more golf-centered approach:***

### EXCEL, <strike>42</strike> <strike>36</strike> 29 bytes

Saved 6 bytes thanks to Magic Octopus Urn
Saved 7 bytes by using Dennis' -1^ approach (which, I just learned, works on arrays in excel)

```
=ABS(SUMPRODUCT(A:A,-1^A:A))
```

Takes a list of integers in A column for input.  Probably can be golfed further, or by using the string version, taking a string in A1 for input.

### EXCEL, 256 bytes

```
=ABS(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,1,""))-2*LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,2,""))+3*LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,3,""))-4*LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,4,""))+5*LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,5,""))-6*LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,6,""))+7*LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,7,""))-8*LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,8,""))+9*LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,9,""))-5*LEN(A1))
```

[image]

Comment: *disclaimer, only works for numbers less than 100 in length*

Comment: Switching to A:A saves 6 bytes and removes that problem.

Comment: Wow, rarely does my constructive criticism save bytes, +1 for your Excel knowledge sir.

Comment: Also, due to `You may take input as a String, as an Integer or as a list of digits.` your 42 byte answer should be the answer you use.

Comment: The first was a humorous attempt, but I'll switch them around.

Comment: I'm bad enough at excel that the humor was lost on me ;).

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 0.5](http://julialang.org/), 19 bytes

```julia
!x=(-1).^x⋅x|>abs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0/f9fscJWQ9dQUy@u4lF3a0WNXWJS8f@0/CKFPIXMPAUNQx0DHUMjHWNjYx0TU0sdIxMzSyDf2ESTi9OhoCgzryRNQ0nVpFRB105B1ag0Jk9JRyFPR0ExJTM9s6RYI09Tkys1L@U/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 54 bytes

```php
for(;~$n=$argn[$i++];)${eo[$n&1]}+=$n;echo abs($e-$o);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkYWhgaGJkrGT9Py2/SMO6TiXPFiwTrZKprR1rralSnZofrZKnZhhbq22rkmedmpyRr5CYVKyhkqqrkq9p/f8/AA)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 57 bytes

store the even and odd sums in an array

```php
for(;~$n=$argn[$i++];)$r[$n&1]+=$n;echo abs($r[0]-$r[1]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkaGBoYmSsZP0/Lb9Iw7pOJc8WLBGtkqmtHWutqVIUrZKnZhirbauSZ52anJGvkJhUrAEUNYjVBZKGsZrW//8DAA)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 57 bytes

store the even and odd sums in two variables

```php
for(;~$n=$argn[$i++];)$n&1?$o+=$n:$e+=$n;echo abs($e-$o);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkaGBoYmSsZP0/Lb9Iw7pOJc8WLBGtkqmtHWutqZKnZmivkq9tq5JnpZIKoqxTkzPyFRKTijVUUnVV8jWt//8HAA)

Comment: 54 bytes: odd sum in `${1}` and even sum in `${0}`: `while(~$n=$argn[$i++])${$n&1}+=$n;echo abs(${1}-${0});`

Comment: @Titus nice I think ` for(;~$n=$argn[$i++];)${eo[$n&1]}+=$n;echo abs($e-$o);` is also a nice variant. Or we can do it more nathematical `for(;~$n=$argn[$i++];$s+=$n)$u+=($n&1)*$n;echo abs($s-2*$u);` and `for(;~$n=$argn[$i++];)$u+=(($n&1)-.5)*2*$n;echo abs($u);` is an interesting way

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <strike>47</strike> <strike>42</strike> <strike>39</strike> <strike>38</strike> <strike>26</strike> 25 bytes

*-1 thanks to nimi*

*-12 thanks to Bruce*

*-1 thanks to xnor*

```hs
abs.sum.map(\x->x*(-1)^x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclBC4IwAMXxe5/iMS9buJHOAg8KEuGlwkuntFg0SdIhmiBEn32tDu93eP@HGp@6be2be9hnx/yU5TtsiwIe/yzqpLTqNopx6kSnelrOPJ2XlAfsMjPbqcYggQuHK2hpwFP0Q2NeoMZHDeoK6KDVXfTToBkMYwxnsiI@CX4LHVJKZ7SOnWG0if@/jEhlvw)

Comment: You can inline `s`: `((*)=<<((-1)^))`.

Comment: It's one byte shorter to just write `(\x->x*(-1)^x)`.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

Thanks to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) for the -1 power trick. Takes input as a list of digits

```
®sm*OÄ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0LriXC3/wy3//0eb6CiY6ihYxgIA)

#### Explanation

```
®sm*OÄ                                               Example [4, 5, 9]
®      # Push -1                                   % STACK: -1
 sm    # Take -1 to the power of every number      % STACK: [1, -1, -1]
         in the input list 
   *   # Multiply with original input              % Multiply [1, -1, -1] with [4, 5, 9] results in STACK: [4, -5, -9]
    O  # Sum them all together                     % STACK: -10
     Ä # Absolute value                            % STACK: 10
       # Implicit print
```

Comment: I can´t follow the explanation. Would you add an example please.

Comment: @Titus there you go. Hope it helps :)

Comment: And here I was with `È2*<*O` like a filthy casual.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 51 bytes

```php
while(~$n=$argn[$i++])$s+=$n&1?$n:-$n;echo abs($s);
```

adds digit to `$s` if odd, subtracts if even. Run as pipe with `-nR`.

or

```php
while(~$n=$argn[$i++])$s+=(-1)**$n*$n;echo abs($s);
```

using Dennis´ `-1` power trick.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>18</s> <s>15</s> 12 bytes

```
#!+/{x-:/x}'
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJw1jctOwzAQRffzFYNAIlFw/UyRY8GeFR9QVSKkSVu1jUvsoFR9fDt2GjSLmTnnetwUjw8ZPQ+koMP1GcAX56fF6dYVDSIO5svuTPLVlNu9GczJdOnyCn7xwgxbxs4Nj52juA8SQxkdR4U5asPHnECF87DJKRxSyoglAIWN90dXUFrZVb22+2bmfFnt6qHalO26nlX2QH/62vmtbR3lkr/mOXX9t+/KypPDidjVypGms4e41L916wA+2mPv8faOn70PEwCLC8Pkwgi74BuyFHhEPCB+Rzwg8c8E4ROTUkaox7eJzEKlUekUVK7HfLyrSJJnejQ8HBdqPjoZVCIylc1ToqOU8RepohOTS0nCp6MiBfgDYCRoKQ==)

Takes input as a list of digits.

- `{x-:/x}'` negate each digit of the input that many times (e.g., negate `4` four times, and `9` nine times). this makes odd digits negative, leaving even digits positive
- `+/` take the sum
- `#!` take the absolute value (and implicitly return)

Answer (score 1):

## J, 14 bytes

```
|-/(2&|+//.[),
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/oPBDW6@hpGajUK2vr6egrRmjoKBlwYQoZYhBSMFIwVTDAljEEQU9hEwVTBEgA)

### explanation

```
|                absolute value of
 -/              the difference between
                 the items on the list returned by this fork
   (2&|          is an item odd? (1 for yes, 0 for no)
       +//.      the "key" verb /. which partitions on above (even / odd) then sums
           [)    identity, ie, the list of digits passed
             ,   turn it into a list (to handle 1 element case)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 28 bytes

```
{abs sum $_ Z*.map(*%2*2-1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OjGpWKG4NFdBJV4hSksvN7FAQ0vVSMtI11Cz9r@1QnFipUKaho2hgpGCsYKJnab1fwA)

Takes a list of digits as input.

- `$_` is the input argument.
- `.map(* % 2 * 2 - 1)` maps each digit to either `1` or `-1` depending on whether the digit is odd or even, respectively.
- `Z*` zips the original list of digits with the even/odd list using multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash <s>141</s> <s>139</s> 99 Bytes

```
while read -n1 a; do
[ $[a%2] = 0 ]&&e=$[e+a]||o=$[o+a]
done
(($[e-o]>0))&&echo $[e-o]||echo $[o-e]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzwjMydVoSg1MUVBN89QIdFaISWfK1pBJTpR1ShWwVbBQCFWTS3VViU6VTsxtqYmH8jKB7K4UvLzUrk0NIDiuvmxdgaamkBVyRn5ChCBmhooJ183Nfb/fzMjY0sA)

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>72</s> 43 bytes

```
b=(d=scan())%%2<1;abs(sum(d[b])-sum(d[!b]))
```

First, `d = scan()` takes the number as input, one digit after the other (thanks to @Giuseppe comment !)
Then, `b = d %% 2 <1` associates to `b` a `TRUE` or `FALSE` value at each index depending on the digits' parity.
Therefore, `b` values are `TRUE` for even numbers, and `!b` are `TRUE` for odd values.

Finaly, `abs(sum(d[b]) - sum(d[!b]))` does the job.

Comment: `<1` is one byte shorter than `==0`, but note that you may take input as a list of digits as well.

Comment: @Giuseppe Well spotted ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 18 bytes

```
{.2%?M|}&+v&+c-!s*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/@/Ws9I1d63plZNu0xNO1lXsVjr////hv@N/hv/N/lvCgA)

Takes input as a list of digits

### Explanation

```
{.2%?M|}&+v&+c-!s*  Implicit input from commandline args
{......}            Foreach loop, runs on each item in the stack..
 .2%                ..Parity check, push 1 if odd, 0 if even
    ?               ..If last item != 0 (pops last item)..
     M              ....Move last item to next stack
      |             ..Endif
        &+          Sum entire stack
          v&+       Switch to next stack and sum entire stack
             c-     Collapse into stack1 and subtract
               !s   Sign check, push 1 if last item is positive, -1 if last item is
                    negative, 0 if last item is 0
                 *  Multiply last item by sign, gets absolute value
                    Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

### TI-BASIC, <s>11</s> 6 bytes

```
abs(sum(Anscos(πAns
```

Takes input as a list. `i²^Ans` saves two bytes over `(-1)^Ans` because we don't need the parentheses.

```
abs(sum(Anscos(πAns
           cos(πAns                  1 for evens, -1 for odds
        Ans                          Multiply by original list
abs(sum(                             Sum the list and take absolute value, which also
                                     fixes rounding errors from cos(.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), <s>16 12 11 10</s> 8 bytes

```
.asm*^tZ
```

**[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.asm%2a%5EtZ&input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B0%5D%0A%5B1%5D%0A%5B3%2C3%2C3%5D%0A%5B4%2C5%2C9%5D%0A%5B2%2C4%2C6%2C9%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D&debug=0)**

---

## How?

```
.asm*^tZ – Full program. Q = input.
   m*^tZ – Raise -1 to the power of each d in Q and multiply by d.
  s      – Sum.
.a       – Absolute value.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 32 bytes

```
00\~:00@(?$-n;
(?\c%:0@2%?$-+i:0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38Agps7KwMBBw15FN8@aS8M@JlnVysDBSBXI1860Mvj/38jEzBIA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 55 bytes

```java
a->{int s=0;for(int d:a)s+=d%2<1?-d:d;return s<0?-s:s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDLboMwELznK/ZSCVRjEUorlUeiXir10FN6i3JwMUSmxCB2SRUhfzs1jyaRDzsz3p0dbSnOwqubXJfyZ2i670plkFUCET6F0tCvABYVSZAt51pJONk/Z0et0sf9AUR7RHdqBSitH@9IVbzodEaq1vyr/tD0vrBEadofNlCkg/A2vWWAqR8XdeuMWEbCxcdUPgTJeuvJSMZtTl2rARN/62GEsRniadHkY5dTjoSQgs5/r9ocBaD3DfuH6zvIght5YvbdaMie2euNBixkL/eCnbUDoZm4maMs4Zcw0ZTIvYbYXZDyE6874o09GFXaKbhomuryhvYwztjuurPTaGtWZvgD)

Naive implementation.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 67 bytes

```c#
namespace System.Linq{a=>Math.Abs(a.Sum(n=>n%2<1)-a.Sum(n=>n%2>1))}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
È2*<*OÄ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cIeRlo2W/@GW//@jTXQUTHUULGMB)

```
        # Input              | 1234567
È       # Is Even?           | [0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
 2*<    # (a * 2) - 1        | [-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1]
    *   # Multiply w/ input. | [-1,2,-3,4,-5,6,-7]
     O  # Sum.               | -10
      Ä # Absolute value of. | 10
```

Comment: `2*` can be `·`

Answer (score 1):

## x86-64 Machine Code, 30 bytes

```
31 C0 99 8B 4C B7 FC F6 C1 01 74 04 01 CA EB 02 01 C8 FF CE 75 ED 29 D0 99 31 D0 29 D0 C3
```

The above code defines a function that accepts a list/array of integer digits and returns the absolute difference between the sum of its even digits and the sum of its odd digits.

[As in C](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13210/list-input-in-c-and-length-argument), assembly language doesn't implement lists or arrays as first-class types, but rather represents them as a combination of a pointer and a length. Therefore, I have arranged for this function to accept two parameters: the first is a pointer to the beginning of the list of digits, and the second is an integer specifying the total length of the list (total number of digits, one-indexed).

The function conforms to the [System V AMD64 calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI), which is standard on Gnu/UNIX systems. In particular, the first parameter (pointer to the beginning of the list) is passed in `RDI` (as this is 64-bit code, it is a 64-bit pointer), and the second parameter (length of the list) is passed in `ESI` (this is only a 32-bit value, because that's more than enough digits to play with, and naturally it is assumed to be non-zero). The result is returned in the `EAX` register.

If it's any clearer, this would be the C prototype (and you can use this to call the function from C):

```
int OddsAndEvens(int *ptrDigits, int length);
```

**Ungolfed assembly mnemonics:**

```
; parameter 1 (RDI) == pointer to list of integer digits
; parameter 2 (ESI) == number of integer digits in list (assumes non-zero, of course)
OddsAndEvens:
   xor  eax, eax              ; EAX = 0 (accumulator for evens)
   cdq                        ; EDX = 0 (accumulator for odds)
.IterateDigits:
   mov  ecx, [rdi+rsi*4-4]    ; load next digit from list
   test cl, 1                 ; test last bit to see if even or odd
   jz   .IsEven               ; jump if last bit == 0 (even)
.IsOdd:                       ; fall through if last bit != 0 (odd)
   add  edx, ecx              ; add value to odds accumulator
   jmp  .Continue             ; keep looping
.IsEven:
   add  eax, ecx              ; add value to evens accumulator
.Continue:                    ; fall through
   dec  esi                   ; decrement count of digits in list
   jnz  .IterateDigits        ; keep looping as long as there are digits left

   sub  eax, edx              ; subtract odds accumulator from evens accumulator

   ; abs
   cdq                        ; sign-extend EAX into EDX
   xor  eax, edx              ; XOR sign bit in with the number
   sub  eax, edx              ; subtract sign bit

   ret                        ; return with final result in EAX
```

Here's a brief walk-through of the code:

- First, we zero out the `EAX` and `EDX` registers, which will be used to hold the sum totals of even and odd digits. The `EAX` register is cleared by `XOR`ing it with itself (2 bytes), and then the `EDX` register is cleared by sign-extending the EAX into it (`CDQ`, 1 byte).
- Then, we go into the loop that iterates through all of the digits passed in the array. It retrieves a digit, tests to see if it is even or odd (by testing the least-significant bit, which will be 0 if the value is even or 1 if it is odd), and then jumps or falls through accordingly, adding that value to the appropriate accumulator. At the bottom of the loop, we decrement the digit counter (`ESI`) and continue looping as long as it is non-zero (i.e., as long as there are more digits left in the list to be retrieved).

  The only thing tricky here is the initial MOV instruction, which uses the most complex addressing mode possible on x86.<sup>*</sup> It takes `RDI` as the base register (the pointer to the beginning of the list), scales `RSI` (the length counter, which serves as the index) by 4 (the size of an integer, in bytes) and adds that to the base, and then subtracts 4 from the total (because the length counter is one-based and we need the offset to be zero-based). This gives the address of the digit in the array, which is then loaded into the `ECX` register.
- After the loop has finished, we do the subtraction of the odds from the evens (`EAX -= EDX`).
- Finally, we compute the absolute value using a common trick—the same one used by most C compilers for the `abs` function. I won't go into details about how this trick works here; see code comments for hints, or do a web search.

__


* The code can be re-written to use simpler addressing modes, but it doesn't make it any shorter. I was able to come up with an alternative implementation that dereferenced `RDI` and incremented it by 8 each time through the loop, but because you still have to decrement the counter in `ESI`, this turned out to be the same 30 bytes. What had initially given me hope is that `add eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]` is only 2 bytes, the same as adding two enregistered values. Here is that implementation, if only to save anyone attempting to outgolf me some effort :-)

```
                    OddsAndEvens_Alt:
31 C0                   xor    eax, eax
99                      cdq
                    .IterateDigits:
F6 07 01                test   BYTE PTR [rdi], 1
74 04                   je     .IsEven
                    .IsOdd:
03 17                   add    edx, DWORD PTR [rdi]
EB 02                   jmp    .Continue
                    .IsEven:
03 07                   add    eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
                    .Continue:
48 83 C7 08             add    rdi, 8
FF CE                   dec    esi
75 ED                   jne    .IterateDigits
29 D0                   sub    eax, edx
99                      cdq
31 D0                   xor    eax, edx
29 D0                   sub    eax, edx
C3                      ret
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 55 bytes

```
lmap e $V {incr s [expr $e*-1**$e]}
puts [expr abs($s)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NctBCoMwEEbhvaf4kVnYQMGYtOBF3EgWKrMQ0hKcVAohZ0@l4vJ98OLii39NATtSCw3dwRgD@@jR2Wd/tLEZqRKOGDBK8GsE7ahr9zdBe/4MGpDW97IdNvI3bCBWd60UsctV@MSLp1kakpsrufwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 45 bytes

***Function; Full number***

```ruby
->n{s=0
n.digits.map{|x|s+=x%2>0?x:-x}
s.abs}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc7fCoIwGAXwe59iEMHGmOxfwoLZg0QXWhRetKQpLJy9@lKboMV3@/vOOc@2fIVra85N9TA6kNx0VtPEpJfqVjU2vRd15523WLstz@nB7YnrE5sWpe1DDebPIz2BDXjngALoKaEeaEBRsgAsAjYA9gVsDfhCcML@hRAiEjW1QIGHQyNUKyh3as4a90gCd1hNjq1HcZnNUgwQcixxhogaqfhZJ2SUPEpEIIv1HIUP)

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 38 bytes

***Function; List of digits***

```ruby
->n{s=0
n.map{|x|s+=x%2>0?x:-x}
s.abs}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc7RCoIwFIDhe59iEMHGNtnmFBbMHkS80CDooiUtwVB7dZvmyizO7XfO@a91eR@OtTncThejB5qa1moWmPBcVG3XdBbrZitStm92tOkDGxal7YcK@JUsY3kONuCRAgZgxyjrgAYMBUvCPeGO8BfhK0LEEgnK/6CIuPFMTe9ghN2gEatvLElM1PvmGCcpjLGaLF8VCiJJ8uGR01BgiRNE1eijn1qXIj0XM0cU8jlGoOEJ)

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 73 bytes

```rust
fn f(mut a:i32)->i32{let mut s=0;while a>0{s+=a%10*(a%2*2-1);a/=10}s.abs()}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc1NCsIwEAXgvaeIhUJSreZPoYb2LiO0GEiDNCkuQs4ek73xLWbxPpi37c6ntFi04HX3CB5acNJP@QYze1Q6N1L1eWkzI5hocKcRWkY7DC3veM@IguvIaHQXeDpMYvm1graYoHBAOe9NW2/sETchNue8QwlRv4XVhVdJCFE1eRuqxuV9@LMnZMGYvg)

## Rust, 68 bytes

This takes a slice of digits rather than an integer.

```rust
fn z(a:&[i32])->i32{a.iter().map(|x|x*(x%2*2-1)).sum::<i32>().abs()}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PoUoj0UotOtPYKFZT1w5IVSfqZZakFmlo6uUmFmjUVNRUaGlUqBppGekaamrqFZfmWlnZAJXZARUkJhVraNaCDMlNzMzT0FSo5lIAgoKizLySnDxFDaXqWiUdoAVq0SY6CqY6CpaxmprWuJQY6SgAVZnBVNX@BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 11 bytes

Credit to [Uriel’s APL solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/131765/74681)

```
1|@#.[*_1^]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT8GwxkFZL1or3jAu9n9qcka@QpqCAReUYQhnKBjBmMYgCOOYKJgqWMI4RkCuGYIL1ANUavIfAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
u$eÞ•ȧ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwidSRlw57igKLIpyIsIiIsIlsxXVxuWzBdXG5bMSwyXVxuWzMsMywzXVxuWzQsNSw5XVxuWzIsNCw2LDldXG5bMSwyLDMsNF0iXQ==)

Port of Jelly.

```
u$eÞ•ȧ
u$e     # Raise -1 to the power of each
   Þ•   # Dot product with the input
     ȧ  # Absolute value
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 24 bytes

```
0spSy[f:2%2*,*l+sp,]lar-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/9@guCC4MjrNykjVSEtHK0e7uEAnNiexSPf/fyMTM0sA)

This is pretty brute force, it just adds or subtracts each number to an accumulator depending on whether it's odd or even.  The post-loop bit is the shortest way to get an `abs()` in Ly I could think of.

```
0sp                       - initialize the backup cell to 0, clear stack
   S                      - convert the number on STDIN to digits on the stack
    y                     - push the number of digits onto the stack
     [f           ,]      - loop decrementing the digit count, stop on 0
       :                  - duplicate the next digit
        2%                - modulo by 2 to get odd/even
          2*,             - do "(x*2)-1" to map 1 to 1, and 0 to -1
             *            - multiple the digit by that 1/-1
              l+sp        - add to backup cell, pop from stack
                    l     - load the final difference from accumulator
                     a    - sort stack (has a 0 and the accumulator val)
                      r   - reverse stack
                       -  - subtract to flip the sign if difference was <0
```

The programs with a positive number on the stack, which is printed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 24 bytes

```
f(l)=abs(total(l(-1)^l))
```

Input as a list of digits.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ggl67yw1jn)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4gifrfuogy)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 6 bytes (12 nibbles)

```
!=+$*+|$%$~~
```

Calculates the absolute difference between the sum of all digits and twice the sum of the odd digits.

```
!=+$*+|$%$~~
!=              # absolute difference between
  +             #   sum of 
   $            #   input
                # and
     +          #   sum of 
       $        #   input 
      |         #   filtered for nonzero when
        %$      #     modulo
          ~     #     2 (default for modulo)
    *           #   multiplied by
           ~    #   2 (default for multiplication)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
b▬m*Σ±
```

Port of [*@Dennis*' Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/131757/52210).

Input as a list of digits.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z/p0bQ1uVrnFh/a@P9/tEEsV7QhCOsYAUljHSAE0iY6pjqWQNpIx0THDMwCygPlTGIB)

**Explanation:**

```python
b      # Push -1
 ▬     # Take -1 to the power of each integer in the (implicit) input-list
  m*   # Multiply the values at the same positions of this list and the (implicit) input
    Σ  # Sum this list together
     ± # Get its absolute value
       # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
üv mx ra
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=7A&code=/HYgbXggcmE&input=MzMz)

Takes input as a digit array

```
üv mx ra     :Implicit input of digit array
ü            :Group by
 v           :  Divisible by 2?
   m         :Map
    x        :  Sum
      r      :Reduce by
       a     :  Absolute difference
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$6\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 4.939 bytes

```
AS*^N1
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJBUypeTjEiLCJbMiw0LDYsOV0iXQ==)

Port of [MathGolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255065/107299). Surprisingly, beats Jelly.

```
AS*^N1 # Input as list of digits
    N1 # -1
   ^   # To the power of each in the input
  *    # Multiply the list of 1s and -1s by each digit
 S     # Sum
A      # Absolute value
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 33 bytes

```ruby
:partition+:odd?|:*&:sum|+:-|:abs
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWNxWtChKLSjJLMvPztK3yU1Lsa6y01KyKS3NrtK10a6wSk4qhCnXKMzJzUhXSU0uKuRQUChTcolXi9Ury4zP1UjLTM0uK9YpSy1KLilNjuVLzUiB6Fuww4DLkMjTiMjY25jIxteQyMjGzBPKNTSDyAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 9 bytes

```
AB$+g*vEg
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJBQiQrZyp2RWciLCIiLCI0IDUgOSIsIi1wIl0=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 26 bytes

```arturo
$=>[abs∑map&'x->x*^0-1x]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?8NJCq7)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 9 \log_{245}(96) \approx \$ 7.41 bytes

```
D1n@z*SZA
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhYrXQzzHKq0gqMcIXyo8II10YY6CkY6CsY6CiaxEDEA) or
[verify all test cases](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abRSilLsOs_qFJcoHyUFXTsFpSifpaUlaboWK10M8xyqtIKjHCH8RVHeEMaCHQZchlyGRlzGxsZcJqaWXEYmZpZAvrEJRB4A).

##### Explanation

```python
D1n@z*SZA  # Implicit input        [1, 2, 3, 4]
D          # Duplicate             [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]
 1n@       # Push -1 ** each       [1, 2, 3, 4], [-1, 1, -1, 1]
    z*     # Multiply elementwise  [-1, 2, -3, 4]
      S    # Sum this list         2
       ZA  # Absolute value        2
           # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## x86-16 machine code, 18 bytes

```
00000000: 33d2 ada8 0174 02f7 d803 d0e2 f579 02f7  3....t.......y..
00000010: dac3                                     ..
```

**Listing**

```
33 D2       XOR  DX, DX         ; result in DX 
        IN_LOOP: 
AD          LODSW               ; next digit 
A8 01       TEST AL, 1          ; odd or even? 
74 02       JZ   EVEN           ; jump if even 
F7 D8       NEG  AX             ; complement to subtract odd digit 
        EVEN: 
03 D0       ADD  DX, AX         ; add to running result 
E2 F5       LOOP IN_LOOP        ; next digit 
79 02       JNS  DONE           ; jump if result is positive 
F7 DA       NEG  DX             ; complement for absolute value
        DONE: 
C3          RET                 ; return to caller
```

Callable function, input list of digits at `DS:SI`, length in `CX`. Output to `DX`.

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 52 bytes

```
(defun f(x)(abs(loop as i in x sum(*(expt -1 i)i))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcjLCoAgEAXQX7m7rkGLoBZ9jj2EAdOhUfDvrc7yHFFMe@d5hZoQ2Bz9bow5K7xBIAkNVm@OvJoWTDPEift06iOpgAEDF6zY/nwB)

Translation of [Dead Possum answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/131759/41789).

Answer (score 0):

### **C#, 59 bytes**

```
Math.Abs(a.Where(x=>(x%2<1)).Sum()-a.Where(x=>x%2>0).Sum())
```

Comment: You may want to add some kind of explanation for this.  Just for the people who don't know C.  As it is, it's kind of just the code.

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 64 bytes

Takes n as int input, uses mod 10 and div 10 to sum from least significant digit and return Absolute value when done.

```
n->{int r=0;for(;n>0;n/=10)r+=n%2>0?-n%10:n%10;return r<0?-r:r;}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##VVBNb4MwDL33V1hISKClLHxsUsloteNUbRy6nSoOGYSKjgaUhG5VxW9naUq7Lgdb79l@fs6W7um0aRnfFl9D233WVQ55TaWEV1pxOE4ARlYqqnTaN1UBO11zVkpUfLPOgIqNdE0rwFbreZ2qaq/seK6qhnsvXH1wKg5pywRVjYASkoFP58eKKxAJJmUjHMLnmPD7xMeuuEu4HczxYsptH8enQARTneAgnjQrYkH6AcwjZqkWWmfaiGJSSUiAs@8rd7YFcMQIcI8uyEfg36DgHwzDEMHsD0cPM12/mQ6iR82EtwJhhCDoDe7JxGR9FzjGh3EWn/25V0vmfia7WmnPpUfbtj48S/1dzqlxjTOXjJ2rg1Rs5zWd8lr96ap0LDsqYtABHFu6NrcQjENo1LzkJDEFP1tY6dKKrbf0HdIlAvbTslyxAiy4g7FlXHg6o5/0wy8)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Your TIO link doesn't seem to match your code, would you mind updating it?

Comment: That TIO is actually [my answer, but to another question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/131760/16236)! O_o

Comment: Fixed! and thanks for the welcome...

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, <s>16</s> 14 Bytes

```
q{si_W\#*}%:+z
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%7Bsi_W%5C%23*%7D%25%3A%2Bz&input=459)

```
q{si_W\#     e# Take -1 to power of digit
*}%          e# Multiply result by digit 
:+z          e# Sum altered digits and return the absolute value
```

Answer (score 0):

**java** , **314 bytes**

```
public  static int f (String s)
{
    char [] m =s.toCharArray();
    int o=0 ,e=0; 
    for(int i =0 ;i<m.length;i++)
    { int n=(int)m[i]-48;
    if(n%2==0)
        e+=n;
    else 
        o+=n;
    }
    return abs(e-o);


   }
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 51 bytes

***Full program; Full number***

Or "bash with awk" for the pedantics.

```bash
grep -o .|awk '{a+=$0%2?$0:-$0}END{print a<0?-a:a}'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P70otUBBN19BryaxPFtBvTpR21bFQNXIXsXASlfFoNbVz6W6oCgzr0Qh0cbAXjfRKrFW/f9/E1PL///yC0oy8/OKQRwA)

### Explanation

```bash
grep -o .| # every /./ on a new line
awk '{
            // a is initialized to 0 cuz awk lol
  a+=$0%2   // Is odd?
    ?$0:-$0 // true -> add +, false -> add -
}
END{
  print a<0?-a:a // to absolute value
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 35 bytes

***Full program; List of digits***

```
{a+=$0%2?$0:-$0}END{print a<0?-a:a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/OlHbVsVA1chexcBKV8Wg1tXPpbqgKDOvRCHRxsBeN9Eqsfb/fxMuUy5LAA)

Technically not the same as [my other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150801/21830). I still think that one is better because using a list of digits feels cheap.

Answer (score 0):

## APL NARS 26 chars

```
{∣(+/-a)+2×+/(2∣a)/a←⍎¨⍕⍵}
```

test

```
  f←{∣(+/-a)+2×+/(2∣a)/a←⍎¨⍕⍵}
  f¨0 1 12 333 459 2469 1234
0 1 1 9 10 3 2
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
u@$Ø.A
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWy0sdVA7P0HNcUpyUXAwVW7DURMdUxxLCAQA)

Port of Dennis's Jelly answer.

##### Explanation

```python
u@$Ø.A  # Implicit input
u@      # Take -1 to the power of
        # each of the digits
  $     # Push the input again
   Ø.   # Take the dot product
     A  # Absolute value
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 3 bytes

```
ṂḋȦ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCLhuYLhuIvIpiIsIiIsIls0LDUsOV0iLCIzLjQuMSJd)

Port of Dennis's Jelly answer.

Certified Vyxal Moment, -1^n and dot product are now one byte builtins.

Input is a list of digits

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org), 17 bytes

```
⌵-∩/+∩▽¬,,◿2.∵⋕°⋕
```

[Test pad](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__RW1PIOKGkCDijLUt4oipLyviiKnilr3CrCws4pe_Mi7iiLXii5XCsOKLlQpbMF8wCiAxXzEKIDEyXzEKIDMzM185CiA0NTlfMTAKIDI0NjlfMwogMTIzNF8yXQriiaEoJnAkIl86IF8gKF8pIjriio86IuKcmOKclCI94oqZLEVtTy7CsOKKnykK)

### Explanation

```
⌵-∩/+∩▽¬,,◿2.∵⋕°⋕­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
             ∵⋕°⋕  # ‎⁡Parse integer into digits
          ◿2.      # ‎⁢Get each digit mod 2
        ,,         # ‎⁣Copy the digits and the mask over
       ¬           # ‎⁤Invert the mask
     ∩▽            # ‎⁢⁡Filter for both masks and arrays
  ∩/+              # ‎⁢⁢Sum both results up
⌵-                 # ‎⁢⁣Get the absolute difference
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).